# Не получается установить git-core на Linux

Tags: linux, git

Ввожу: sudo aptitude install git-core
Выдаёт: «git-core» является виртуальным пакетом, предоставляемым:
  git:i386 git 
Для установки следует выбрать один.
Не удалось применить некоторые действия, прерываем работу

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Comment: Установить `git`: `apt-get install git`

Comment: В вопросах про Linux стоит указывать название и версию дистрибутива

Comment: @Drakonoved, все известные дистрибутивы предоставляют git в пакетах, не стоит ставить вручную, лучше рекомендовать ставить через штатный менеджер пакетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `bash` в `ubuntu`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install git
```

Через `ansible`:

```
- name: Install Git
  become: yes
  block:
    - apt_repository:
        repo: ppa:git-core/ppa
        state: present
      when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
    - apt:
        name:
          - git
        state: latest
        install_recommends: yes
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'
    - package:
        name:
          - git
        state: latest
```